# Check if object completely passes another object Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm in the middle of a game where the character travels through different corridors and hallways to get their goal. As the player goes through the corridors, I want the walls to disappear when the player "passes" it. This might sound confusing so I provided a picture of what I want to happen:

[image: Diagram]

I already have the function that makes the walls invisible, but I don't know how I should call it. I've tried calling it when

```
player.position.z > wall.position.z
```

But that causes each wall to become invisible when the player is halfway past it (at it's transform); I want to call it when the player is COMPLETELY past it. Is there any way I can check if the player is completely past the mesh of the wall on the z axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will the player be able to travel back down that hallway? If so, this is an easy way to check if the camera is facing away from the wall in question.

```
// Please cache the variables; I'm using properties for simplicity's sake.

float maxViewAngle = Camera.main.fieldOfView / 2f + 20;  // +20 for some padding

Vector3 difference = Camera.main.transform.position - wall.transform.position;

float angleDifference = Vector3.Angle( Camera.main.transform.forward, difference );

if ( angleDifference > maxViewAngle )
{
  wall.HideThyself();  // Or whatever
}
```

Your posted solution, `player.position.z > wall.renderer.bounds.max.z`, will only work in one direction along one axis. If your levels are one-dimensional and only move forward, then this is fine!

Edit: I should mention that if your walls are static (immutable and marked as "static" in the inspector) then you can much more easily use [occlusion culling (unity docs)](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) if you have Unity Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Solved It! Found that renderer has a "max" attribute. I just used:

```
player.position.z > wall.renderer.bounds.max.z
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how will this work when your player turns a corner and is walking down the 'x' axis and not 'z'?